# 2000 Oldsmobile Alero stalls at decreased speed

Tags: troubleshooting, car, repair, stall, oldsmobile

I have a 2000 Oldsmobile Alero that has been stalling and sometimes dying at decreased speeds or when coming to a stop. I can be coming off a ramp on the interstate, coming up to a stop sign, or driving around the parking lot. The problem started just after my O2 sensor blew out on the highway. I was able to stop before losing all my engine oil. So far we have replaced the fuel filter, both O2 sensors, TPS, and AIC valve. We have also used fuel system cleaner. The problem seems to worsen the longer distance the car is driven...almost like the engine has to be very hot. It's not over heating though. There are no error codes and the mechanic we took it to cannot reproduce the problem. We are at our witts end and money is running low. Please help!

Comment: correction...the OIL PRESSURE SENSOR is what blew out. The problem can also happen when shifting from park or drive to reverse

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!